# How to update cordova sencha touch app from google play store?

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, phonegap-build

I am phonegap/cordova sencha touch developer. Whenever I release a new version say 0.0.5 to google app store, I have to uninstall the 0.0.4 version first then install new one to see the update changes. The update is not visible when I update from store. Need help.

I change the `android-versionCode` every time when I upload.

Comment: Are you embedding a "production" build into the cordova app? If yes, your Sencha Touch app loads itself into localstorage and then does not update correctly. Using `localStorage.clear()` on app close should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel `appcache` in your build. It causes the browser to cache the code. [Here](http://extjs-senchatouch.com/index.php/2015/08/24/enable-extjs-appcache/) is a how-to for that.

As an alternative way (or the above method doesnt work), open `.sencha/app/production.defaults.properties` set all caching variables to false. If your build type is `native`, then you have to edit `native.defaults.properties`.

Example:

```
app.output.cache.enable=false
app.output.manifest.enable=false
app.output.deltas.enable=false
app.output.archive.enable=false

enable.standalone.manifest=false
```